# Nested Json Xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, json

I've been looking through stack and I cant get nested json to work,

I keep getting this error and my data is not being loaded into the table view. My code works if i dont used nested.

2013-02-04 13:17:20.961 Big Wave App[2338:c07] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7165510

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blog.bigwavemedia.co.uk/?json=get_recent_posts"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];


}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData{
    [data appendData:theData];
}


-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
    [mainTableView reloadData];

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"error" message:@"the download could not complete" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorView show];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

}
-(int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return  1;
}

-(int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [news count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"] valueForKey:@"id"];

    return cell;
}
```

Any help would be great this is my first xcode project, all new to me.

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://blog.bigwavemedia.co.uk/?json=get_recent_postshttp://blog.bigwavemedia.co.uk/?json=get_recent_posts

Comment: You're trying to use an object as an array whereas it's a dictionary. Check your logic and the JSON.

Comment: Can you help me? what do i need to change?

Comment: what value from your response you want to display in tableview?

Comment: @BrentFrench I don't know - you haven't provided the JSON data nor the relevan code (the code you listed is unrelated to the error). You have to ensure that an array is really an array and not a dictionary - analyse the structure of your JSON by reading the specs on json.org.

Comment: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://blog.bigwavemedia.co.uk/?json=get_recent_postshttp://blog.bigwavemedia.co.uk/?json=get_recent_posts Here is the Json, and I want to display the post ID. Thanks

Comment: @BrentFrench your response return you hall dictionary of data, you have to decide which data you want to display in tableview?

Comment: I just want to display the ID of the posts, so i guess 505, 489 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add [sbjson](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) library in your project.and try to using this code instead of yours.
in .h file

```
NSMUtableArray * idArray;
```

and in .m file

```
        #import "SBJson.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{       

idArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 NSString *post =@"";

                NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blog.bigwavemedia.co.uk/?json=get_recent_posts"];

                NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

                NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
                [request setURL:url];
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
                //[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
                // [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
                [request setHTTPBody:postData];

                //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

                NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
                NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
                NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];



                //NSLog(@"Response code: %d", [response statusCode]);
                if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
                {
                    NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    // NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);                    

                    SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
                    NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];


                    //NSLog(@"json data is : %@",jsonData);

                    NSArray *allDataArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
                    allDataArray= [jsonData objectForKey:@"posts"];


                    for(int i=0;i<[allDataArray count];i++)
                    {
                        NSDictionary *tempDictionary = [allDataArray objectAtIndex:i];


                        if([tempDictionary objectForKey:@"id"]!=nil)
                        {

                            [idArray addObject:[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"id"]];
                        }

                    }

                } else {
                    if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                    [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Does not find any data!"];
                }


            }
            @catch (NSException * e) {
                NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
                [self alertStatus:@"Data not found." :@"Does not find any data!"];
            }
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

**UPDATE**

And for tableview add this

```
-(int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return  1;
}

-(int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [news count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [idArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, So i add this all in the viewDidLoad part or my m?

Comment: and dont forget to add SBJson library

Comment: I think i did everything correct and iv got errors can i zip up project so you can take a look. I will tick you up as soon as its fixed

Comment: www.bigwavemedia.co.uk/App.zip

Comment: can i get your mail address bcoz i dont have server to upload.

Comment: brentfrench@bigwavemedia.co.uk, Thanks mate

Comment: i have sended you mail which have running project and explain what mistake it have.

Comment: and yes i have changed icon bcoz file you have sended to me does not contain any images,so plz add it again.

Comment: Thankyou so much! Can i contact you for paid work in future if i get stuck?